# Theories on Triangles

Tags: geometry

Number of obtuse angled triangles with integral sides whose longest side has length 13 units.

Is there any theorem or approach to solve such problems.

I tried to use the triangle theorem which states that if 2 sides of a triangle  are known the third side can have values ranging from difference of the given sides to the addition of these sides.

Answer (score 3):

**An approach:**

WLOG let $a\geqslant b$, then we have $0< b \leqslant a < 13$,  $a+b > 13$ and $a^2+b^2< 169$.  You may then want to count with $a = 12, 11, ...7$

Comment: My bas, you are perfectly right. Sorry for this silly remark that I erase.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

From cosine law, we have 
$$a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta=13^2$$
Since $\theta$ is obtuse $\implies -1<cos\theta<0$.
$$a^2+b^2<13^2<(a+b)^2$$